# Error is generated with the sort method while sorting the values inside a vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl, g++

When we are compiling the below code using g++ in debian machine, then following errors are generated...can anyone pls help me why the error are? I tried by commenting sort line then error dissappears however our task requires sorting to be done then what can be the possible solution

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Here is a simple struct
struct MyStruct
{
   int Num;
   // Define the operator <
   bool operator <(const MyStruct& Rhs)
   {
      return (Num < Rhs.Num);
   }
};

int main()
{
   vector<MyStruct> MyVector;
   // Let the size be 5.
   MyVector.resize(5);
   // Push 5 instances of MyStruct with Num ranging
   // from 5 to 1
   MyStruct TestStruct;
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {
      TestStruct.Num = 5 - i;
      MyVector[i] = TestStruct;
   }
   // Now sort the vector
   sort(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end());
   // Try to display Num for each element. It is sorted
   for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {
      cout << MyVector[i].Num << '\n';
   }
   return 0;
```

## }

Output:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
>                    from testvect.cpp:3: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of
>   ‘_RandomAccessIterator
>   std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator,
>   _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Tp = MyStruct]’: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:2309:70:   required
>   from ‘_RandomAccessIterator
>   std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator,
>   _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]’ /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:2340:54:   required from ‘void
>   std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator,
>   _Size) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Size = int]’ /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5476:4:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >]’ testvect.cpp:33:41:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:2271:4: error: passing ‘const
>   MyStruct’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool MyStruct::operator<(const
>   MyStruct&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. As comparison method does not change object it operate upon, mark it `const`. It should help.

Comment: even after marking it as const, it is producing the same error....

Comment: I compiled with `-std=c++14 -O2 -Wall` and added @Revolver_Ocelot's const suggestion, without error. [Link](http://cpp.sh/8xsag)

Comment: working with c++14 compiler....thnx...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use quite dated compiler where stl used const& parameters, in more modern versions those are passed by rvalue references and does not require const operator<, so to fix it:

Change:

```
  bool operator <(const MyStruct& Rhs)
```

to

```
  bool operator <(const MyStruct& Rhs) const
                                       ^^^^^
```

Alternately, use a later version of the compiler which supports more modern versions of C++ and then enable the more modern versions with '-std=c++11' or '-std=c++14'.

Comment: can u pls share the concept of passing by rvalue reference??
hows that can be achieved???

Comment: @FarhanPatel this is large topic, you should read on it, ie:http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html, In your code I dont see it to be of any use (I mean a constructor/copy operator with rvalue reference as parameter).

Comment: also @marcin., pls suggest further reading for stl associative and sequential containers....thnx and regards

Comment: What does rvalue parameters have to do with the operator being `const` or not?

Comment: I suppose it has more to do with differences in STL implementations, I am able to compile original code with VS2005 (I see it uses non const iterators for comparisions) but gcc4.8.2 fails. From http://apt-browse.org/browse/debian/wheezy/main/i386/libstdc++6-4.7-dev/4.7.2-5/file/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h line 2271 I can see, that pivot is const& when doing comparison so it requires const operator<. In VS2015 on the other hand rvalue semantics are used here.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// Here is a simple struct
struct MyStruct
{
   int Num;
   // Define the operator <
   bool operator <(const MyStruct& Rhs)const
   {
      return (Num < Rhs.Num);
   }
};

int main()
{
   vector<MyStruct> MyVector;
   // Let the size be 5.
   MyVector.resize(5);
   // Push 5 instances of MyStruct with Num ranging
   // from 5 to 1
   MyStruct TestStruct;
   int i = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {
      TestStruct.Num = 5 - i;
      MyVector[i] = TestStruct;
   }
   // Now sort the vector
   sort(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end());
   // Try to display Num for each element. It is sorted
   for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {
      cout << MyVector[i].Num << '\n';
   }
   return 0;
```